# Is it possible to auto repair (on the fly) Django corrupted Mysql table upon exception?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django with Mysql as part of a product. Occasionally some table gets corrupted and when accessing the table I get the exception:

```
InternalError: (145, "Table 'some_table' is marked as crashed and should be repaired")
```

I then need to run a sql script which uses REPAIR TABLE command to fix the issue.

My questions are:

1. Is there a django mechanism which will detect this issue, run "REPAIR TABLE some_table", print notification and then retry the operation which has failed?
2. if not - is it reasonable to put a decorator to django interface functions like filter, save etc.?

of course if the operation will fail again after repair I will want to print something rather than continue to run the db operation again.

I appreciate any answer especially one with an elaborated python example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there isn't a Django mechanism for that, and there shouldn't be. If you "occasionally get corrupt tables", there's something broken with your host that you should fix.

Comment: You should probably attempt to fix the root cause of the issue (why are the tables getting corrupted) rather than slapping on a band-aid (calling repair). It's the right way of solving this problem and you'll thank yourself in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that this would be an incredibly DevOps feature to have, but I dare say that if your table is randomly getting corrupted and the extent of your caring is to run `REPAIR TABLE some_table;` when it errors out, you should probably skip straight to

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ENGINE=BLACKHOLE;
```

That will be a lot more robust on an otherwise unstable system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I take back on the word "occasionally" - is there a way to fix table corruption "on the fly" (while failing to read or write to the DB) and then try again the same action?

Comment: No, there isn't. You are going to have to fix your database server so it doesn't randomly get corrupted. I have seen table corruption twice in the last 15 years, once due to a bug in MySQL and once due to faulty hardware. If you are seeing it regularly, it is a virtual certainty you have faulty hardware.